# How do you read an Oracle .dmp file on a Mac?

Tags: windows, database, sql, oracle, mac

I have a ~1GB `.dmp` file I'd like to get the data out of and I'm on a Mac. Is there any way to do this without either buying Oracle or finding a windows machine?

Can you import `.dmp` files into PostgreSQL or other SQL/NoSQL databases that are easy to get running on a Mac (MySQL, SQLite3, MongoDB)?

If not, what are the options? Even being able to convert the `.dmp` to a CSV for free would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.dmp` files are a proprietary Oracle format, I am not aware of any third party software that can read it entirely although using the 'strings' on the command line on a Mac or *nix machine should reveal some of the SQL DDL, you probably can't read the data itself. 
The free 'Oracle Express Edition' is available for Linux so on your Mac (Intel-based?) you could:

1. Install some virtualization software on Mac OSX that can run Linux such as [Virtual Box](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html#vbox) or VMware.
2. Download and install the free [Oracle 11.2 Express Ed.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html) for Linux x64 or, if the licensing allows, use one of the [Pre-built Developer VMs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) that has Oracle 11.2 already installed.